# Find the available width of an button inside Intrinsicheight

Tags: flutter

Here is my code, I want to find the available width space in ElevatedButton.

We can use `LayoutBuilder` and `BoxConstraints`, But the issue is that we cannot use `LayoutBuilder` inside the `IntrinsicHeight`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button with Long Text 1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 2'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 3'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for package:boxy, which can do an amazing job of intercepting the layout algorithm at the right point.

Comment: The official docs on `Intrinsichight` class suggest that `This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible.`, can you try the layout on flutter widget tree without that widget?